# Why does the website allow me to scroll to the right?

Tags: html, css

I have been having trouble with my code and I don't know why. The site allows me to scroll to the right, like I have some image or something there, but I don't. Why is this happening?

I have looked into margin but I don't find anything.

```css
body {
  background-image: url('icon/background.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 1439px 851px;
  margin-top: 850px;
}

div.relative {
  position: relative;
  left: 255px;
  bottom: 805px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="relative">
    <img src="icon/folder.png">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `left: 255px;` <-- the culprit

Comment: what can i do to fix it but keep the same positon of folder.png as now?

Comment: margin-left and not left

Comment: Because you have created a div that is 100% width and moved it left by 255px:
`100% + 255px = scrollbar`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The div is `width: auto` so when it is rendered, it takes up as much space as is available horizontally.

It is also `position: relative` and `left: 255px`, so it is offset by 255 pixels from the left. This does not affect its size (which is determined before the positioning is applied).

Since it is sticking almost 255 pixels out of the side of the document, a scrollbar is added so the user can see it.

---

If you want to give an element a left margin, then give it a left margin. Don't mess around with positioning.

Relative positioning is almost never useful when combined with `left`, `top`, etc. It is mostly useful for providing a context for the absolute positioning of an element's descendants.

Comment: This is a great and thorough answer.

Comment: Thank you Quentin, this answer gave me some knowledge i can use later on too! /Lukas

Comment: @mockomocki when you are allowed to, please mark this answer as accepted to help future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have the `left` property set to `255px`

```
div.relative {
  position: relative;
  left: 255px;
  bottom: 805px;
}
```

It's moving the div over 255px, so it's creating the scroll.

Answer (score 0):

So, I set "width: 20px" to the class and it fixed, try it

```css
div.relative {
  position: relative;
  left: 255px;
  bottom: 805px;
  width: 20px;
}
```